# A rebus to 'Play' with

Tags: wordplay, rebus

First crack at rebus (Suggestions are welcome)

[image]

Comment: Wow... there are downvotes as soon as I posted the question(and again without reasons)...almost made me think that it is system generated response

Comment: im still working on the solution but thanks to this post i learnt the origin for the Peace simbol ☮

Comment: I honestly have no idea why this was downvoted, it seems legit. The only reason I can think of is the unoriginal title, but that shouldn't be why someone up votes/ down votes

Comment: the title say: 'play' and my lord is GabeN ... maybe is something there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is

> To infinity and beyond! *(Buzz Lightyear from Toy Story)*

The colon is used in comparisons to mean "to". `while(1)` produces an infinite loop. The Venn diagram adds the word "and". The final bit is "Bey on D" because Beyonce?

---

*Previous solution:*
Okay, here's my guess:

> :O *(surprised face)*

It starts with a colon, then shows a Venn diagram indicating the intersection between two things. The way I read those things are "loop" (`while(1)` produces a programming loop) and "go" ($\frac{god}{d} = go$). The intersection of these two words is the single letter "o".

Comment: nice one! I was stuck cause I set *while(1)* as *always* or *for ever*

Comment: but maybe is not correct cause you dont need to "devide" by d because god works also with the intersection ...

Comment: OMG!! Very nice explanation! +1(for finding intersection between loop and go! I did not even think about that while posting),Unfortunately not the answer.

Comment: I think you're right with the edit. Although Bey on D because Beyonce? ._.

Comment: Bey is a word for a Turkish chieftain apparently.

Comment: @AurelBílý Ha, I thought the exact same thing, but it's probably in reference to Serapis... who I've definitely never heard referred to as merely "Bey?" (Bey is the queen, not the lord.)

Comment: My other thought was "BAE" which might fit as a homonym. Both seem like a stretch, but I like Beyonce better.

Comment: maybe its bee because my lord = queen bee, also reference to lord - lorde ? so ''bee on d''

Comment: @Aurel, yeah I read the Wikipedia page about it, too. "Bey" is informally used nowadays to mean similar to the French "monsieur", which literally translates to English as "my lord". A two-step leap for that clue, but ... I guess?

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

While(1) indicates:

> infinite loop, here 1 means true

[image]

indicates:

> Semaphore(a system of sending messages by holding the arms or two flags or poles in certain positions according to an alphabetic code). It indicates symbol "D".

Comment: That's only _half_ of "peace" though

Comment: Than is not "peace" symbol, though you are close with the while(1)

Comment: On reverse search, the symbol indicates peace.

Comment: perhaps it isn't needed. semaphores are terminology in programming, same as while loops. maybe it has a double meaning.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404.. Yes we have to crack it..

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 you are right ... maybe has something to do with it... also my lord is GabeN

Comment: Spot on with the semaphore symbol!

Answer (score 2):

Some possible interpretations of the Venn Diagram:

> - while(1) is the same as "always"
>  - @Ian_MacDonald discovered the right side of the diagram could represent "$god/d$ = $go$"
>  - the intersection would then be *"Always on the go."*

I have no idea what the two dots on the left mean.

> If it is, in fact, a colon, it could mean that the colon (double meaning) is always on the go, but that is a rather unsanitary possibility and I hesitate to think it could be the intended answer.

Comment: 'my lord' represents a different thing. Also think of while(1) as a programmer

Comment: being that i am a programmer, i cannot think of while(1) as anything but a programmer xD I'll give it some more thought